# validate javascript expressions

Tags: javascript, testing

I have done a test for a gender expression -

```
function gender()
{
    var gender = document.form1.radio[0].checked;
    var gender1 = document.form1.radio[1].checked;  
        if(gender || gender1)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            errorMsg = errorMsg + "please select your gender\n" 
        }
}
```

but I would like to be able to write it so that there is no need for an empty positive outcome like this -

```
if ((alphabetic.test(fname)== false) || (alphabetic.test(lname)== false))
{
alertmsg = alertmsg + "Name should be in alphabets:" + "\n";
}
```

I am sorry if I appear to be very stupid, I am a complete beginner. any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: what was your question again?

Comment: Please do not use checkboxes for gender input. It is not fair: http://intersexroadshow.blogspot.de/2012/02/on-sexgender-checkboxes.html

Comment: I would also, for clarity, maybe name your variables after the actual gender as opposed to gender and gender1.  Also a great programmer would account for the possibility of new genders :|.

Comment: I was told on my course that my testing code was too complex and that I should re-write it so there is no need for empty positive outcomes and that I should use the same testing method like the first and last name.  I'm not sure what they mean

Comment: sorry, yes I'll the gender for something else

Answer (score 1):

```
function gender()
{
var gender = document.form1.radio[0].checked;
var gender1 = document.form1.radio[1].checked;  
    if(!(gender || gender1))
    {
        errorMsg = errorMsg + "please select your gender\n" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
if(!gender && !gender1) {
    errorMsg = errorMsg + "please select your gender\n" 
}
```

Comment: function gender()
{
var gender = document.form1.radio[0].checked;
var gender1 = document.form1.radio[1].checked;  
if(!gender && !gender1) {
    errorMsg = errorMsg + "please select your gender\n" 
}

Comment: this would make sure they have selected at least one of the 2 radio buttons?

Comment: @user2073133 Yes, it will. If none is selected, the final result will be `true`, and the error message will be appended. In any other case, the final result will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to do but, try using the logical NOT "!":

```
function gender()
{
    var gender = document.form1.radio[0].checked;
    var gender1 = document.form1.radio[1].checked;  
    if !(gender || gender1)
    {
        errorMsg = errorMsg + "please select your gender\n" 
    }

}
```

Comment: I just need a test to check that at least one gender is selected.  A Test that is better than my original one, thank you